# Querying SalesForce DB Records using REST API

Tags: rest, salesforce, soql

I have tried implementing like this to get data from SalesForce DB using the REST api,

```
uri= ...."/query?q=Select+Acc_Name__c+From+Account__c+where+Acc_ID__c+=+'123456'+Limit+5

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
```

This is the syntax i found in [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)

```
URI
/vXX.X/query/?q=SOQL query
```

while this works, I don't really want to expose my query like this in uri, Is there an another efficient way to achieve the same operation using REST api ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the way the REST API works.  You can implement your own methods via an Apex Restful Web Service.  This would allow you to define a method that receives the querystring via a POST (you could even encrypt it first if you wanted to).

[Exposing Apex Classes as RESTful Web Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm)